# If/Else statement Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I'm getting an HTTP error which makes me think I need an else statement here but I can't figure out where to add URL check to avoid the error (see image):

[image]

```
      <% 
       title = ''
       if video.video_type == 'wistia'
          v = VideoInfo.new("#{video.video_link}")
          title = v.title
          thumb_url = v.thumbnail_small
       end 
      %>
```

Comment: use byebug and see what you are getting in v.title

Comment: I think I just need a valide if/else statement here. I want if there isn't a valide URL, to display 'no title' or 'no url' instead of causing an error.

Comment: you can do that, I suggested byebug to make sure that you were getting the video file.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be setting up `v` like you expect. I'm not sure what your key is for the `video_link` value you're passing in, but it might serve you well to be more explicit:

`v = VideoInfo.new(video_link: "#{video.video_link}")`

I don't know all that this particular piece is doing, but you might also consider if you want to `VideoInfo.create` rather than `VideoInfo.new` here. There isn't enough information here for me to know for sure.

I recommend some `puts` or `binding.pry` debugging in this `if` method to make sure you have the values you expect by the time you get to the problematic line.

Comment: I think I just need a valid if/else statement here. I want if there isn't a valid URL, to display 'no title' or 'no URL' instead of causing an error.